# Updating Your Loki Service Node using the Loki Launcher

Tags: monero-forks, loki, random-x, random-xl

The Loki network is going to be upgrading to v4 in the coming week to prepare for RandomX mining and as a Storage Server for messaging. Currently I am on version 3. How do I update my Loki SN to get ready for this hardfork?

Comment: Answer below also works for v5 update as of 2019-OCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First login to your service node and make sure you are using the user that launches the loki-launcher. Following the guide: https://lokidocs.com/ServiceNodes/UpdateGuide/ -- My user is **snode**.

```
For those looking for a one liner, you can do this otherwise skip it: 

$ su snode
$ loki-launcher stop; sudo npm install -g loki-launcher; sudo loki-launcher download-binaries; sudo loki-launcher fix-perms snode; loki-launcher start
```

Then make sure you stop the loki service using:

> **loki-launcher stop**

If that doesn't work you can stop it like this too:

> **sudo systemctl stop lokid.service**

Once stopped, we can proceed to update loki. First update loki-launcher using:

> **sudo npm install -g loki-launcher**

Then update lokid binaries using:

> **sudo loki-launcher download-binaries**

And make sure your permissions are fixed also by:

> **sudo loki-launcher fix-perms snode**

To double check goto your folder:

> cd ~/.loki

And see if any of the files or folders have root as the owner. If it does, change it to snode: **sudo chown snode:snode < folder/file >**

---

Now lets start your lokid: **loki-launcher start**

Then do a: **loki-launcher client**

Let it wait as it will have to scan the blockchain for the new version. My vps took about 10-15 mins to do the scanning. You should see this:

[image]

When done, you'll see **SYNCHRONIZED OKAY**

And check on your SN status with: **print_sn_status**

---

Next make sure your **STORAGE SERVER** is working. Just do a: **loki-launcher status** -- if it shows **OFFLINE**, you can try to launch it manually to see if its throwing errors like this: **/opt/loki/bin/loki-storage 0.0.0.0 23023** --- I had the issue where it was showing OFFLINE, it was due to my ~/.loki/storage folder was owned by root. A chown to snode fixed it.

Also be aware of:

> IP Address: 0.0.0.0
>
> Storage Server Port: 0
>
> Downtime Credits: 720 blocks (about 24.00 hours)

Its suppose to look like that as the fork hasn't happened yet.